# How do I generate files using npm for node project

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to be able to to write this in the console:

```
someCommand my-project
```

and it will generate on my root project these files:

```
views/art/my-project.jade
public/my-project/my-project.styl
public/my-project/my-project.js
```

How do I do it? Where do I start? Does it require that I will write my own npm package?

Comment: Have a look at [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/).

Comment: Yeoman seems to generate full webapp. I'm looking for something more specific and customized

Comment: You can write custom generators for Yeoman. It could be useful if you plan to generate a full project structure (e.g. build script, directory structure, git ignore files, package.json etc etc).

Answer (score 0):

Start your program with:

```
!/usr/bin/env node
```

Mark the file as executable and place it somewhere in your `$PATH`

Then use the [file system module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

There is no need to write your own npm package, but doing so is generally a good idea as it lets your organise your program and have it in an installable package. See the [package.json documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html) (in particular the section marked *bin*).